# What do these faction modifiers do?

Tags: tropico-4

I understand that depending on how satisfied a faction is with your rule, they will grant special benefits or penalties.  However, I don't understand these:

[image]

What do these modifiers mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Tropico, any of the various leader characters you can play as have an individual list of perks and faction modifiers (which present various benefits).

Basically, this lets you know that Religious Tropicans inherently dislike leaders with the "Man of the People" or "Alcoholic" trait, and inherently like leaders who are "Charismatic". t

This way you can play to your leader's strengths, focusing on either the factions who inherently dislike you (so that more people like you overall) or focusing on those already friendly to you (so that they like you so much, it doesn't matter *what* the Religious Tropicans think!).

Comment: There are some that aren't based on your leaders traits, but those explain themselves if you hover over them.

Comment: Also, in this particular case: remove all churches and set your media/high schools to not give any religious airtime or education, thereby diminishing the religious faction's size by denying them new members. It doesn't matter if the five remaining religious tropicans think you're the hybrid hate baby of Satan, Hitler and Pol Pot when the other 245 non-religious tropicans think you're the best thing since sliced bread.

Comment: N.B. you should make sure you have at least a token military in place before you deliberately alienate anyone, even a minority. Being deposed by a force of 2 rebels is quite annoying.

Answer (score 1):

You can view the impacts of each personal trait by hovering the cursor over it when you're selecting a dictator, before starting a scenario. Faction-specific effects will be a simple % gain or loss of standing.